# assigning read/write privileges for a folder to a user in CentOS 7

Tags: files, permissions, users, chmod

I am logged into a `CentOS 7` server as `root`.  I created a folder `/somefolder`.  I want `someusername` to be able to write to that folder via `scp` from a remote computer.  What command should I run so that `someusername` is able to type in `scp /some/directory/in/remotepc someusername@centos7server:/somefolder/` and successfully transfer the file?

I can guess something like `chmod -R u+rw /somefolder`, but that is just a guess.  And how would I specify which user?

Comment: Try `chmod 644 /path/to/some/folder && chown -v someuser:somegroup /path/to/some/folder` where someuser and somegrouup are usually the same value.

Comment: @eyoung100 Thank you.  Does the syntax change if there are no groups at the moment?  It is just the one user.

Comment: The default unless you deleted `/etc/groups` is that a user someuser belongs to a group of the same name, ie someuser.

Comment: @eyoung100 Thank you.  And I think 6 means read-write.  But what does 4 mean?  And 644?

Comment: Google "Octal Permissions" and read [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html), esp. Default user groups.  I'm on my way to bed.  I'd explain it but I'm too tired :)

Comment: @eyoung100 I am getting an `scp permission denied` error after trying your code.  I will read your links.

Comment: @eyoung100 It works when I change 644 to 700, because this particular file is an executable.  This question is answered.  If you want to write it up tomorrow as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.  Thank you and sleep well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Anthon's answer is technically correct, I'm writing this one to explain where Octal Permissions come from, and how to calculate them. Octal Permissions is one of the most important concepts in the  *nix world.

### Why This Concept is Important

Since the [Birth of Unix Circa 1969 -1974](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/hist.html) on a [discarded DEC PDP-7](http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/the-strange-birth-and-long-life-of-unix/) (see [photo and history](http://www.soemtron.org/pdp7.html)) and [Linus Torvalds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) creation of Linux circa 1994, as a Unix like clone, file permissions have always existed at a Granular level.

Granular file permissions means that if need be, a user can grant permissions starting at the file level, and work their way up the ladder to the directories, then to the directories' parents, all the way to the root.

Windows on the other hand, did not have [granular permissions until the release of Windows 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx), and even now Windows Permissions are very tough to manage without the use of the GUI Window, or an add on [Active Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Server to achieve the behavior of a *nix system.

---

### How Octal Permissions Work

All *nix file permissions work on 2 concepts:

1. The User class - a.k.a. UGO (**U**ser, **G**roup, **O**thers)
2. The Mode class - a.k.a. RWX (**R**ead, **W**rite e**X**ecute)

As Jared Heeschen states in [his article](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/using-chmod-octal-mode):

> Now we look at the other way chmod can be used - with numbers. This is
> the more commonly-used format, but also the least user-friendly.

Since a computer works in binary, the file permissions also work in binary.  If we look at a permission string as:

```
 UGO    UGO    UGO    UGO
 ========================
 111    110    101    100
```

when converted to base 10, we get:

```
 UGO    UGO    UGO    UGO
 ========================
 111    110    101    100
  7      6      5      4
```

*Thanks, Jared for the Math*

---

### The Final Step

Having converted our binary representations to decimal numbers, we can now combine the permission for all three parts of the user class:

`ls -al`:

```
 U  G  O
======== 
-rwxrwxrwx   owner  group  file-count  date  filename
```

**Mode**: 0777

```
 U  G  O
========   
-rw-r--r--   owner  group  file-count  date  filename
```

**Mode**: 0644

As a shortcut, we can use this [Handy Permissions Calculator and Decoder](http://permissions-calculator.org/).  Once these octal numbers are understood, a user can use the `chmod` command and use the octal sequences to quickly change modes. As always, for more, type `man chmod`

---

### References

[How Linux file permissions work](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-linux-file-permissions-work/)
[Using chmod - octal mode](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/using-chmod-octal-mode)

Answer (score 11):

For a user `someusername` to be able to write in folder, that was initially made by root, you need to change the `rwx` permissions and/or the owner resp. group. If you restrict the permissions then `someusername` needs to be either owner or group member.

If you do `chmod 777 /somefolder`, everyone can read and write, including `someusername`.

If you do `chmod 770 /somefolder`, then `someusername` has to be member of the group owning `/somefolder` and you additionally have to do:

```
chgrp someusername /somefolder
```

(assuming that there is a group `someusername` created when the user `someusername` was created, as is nowadays often the case. You can get the groups for `someusername` by typing `id someusername`).

If you do `chmod 700 /somefolder`, then `someusername` has to be owner of `/somefolder` and you additionally have to do:

```
chown someusername /somefolder
```

For a directory you need the execute bit set in order to access files and directories inside that directory. Therefore `644` is seldom appropriate for a directory and `700`, `755`, `750` permissions are much more often seen on directories.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to provide an insightful answer.  Since eyoung100 gave me the answer via comments 2 hours before yours, I am marking the first correct answer as accepted, even though yours is also correct and adds its own insights.  Thank you.

Comment: ty so much pointing out differences of the chown chmod etc.

Comment: This 'calculator' converting the bits to read, write, execute permissions for Owners, Groups, and Public helped me grok the above: https://chmod-calculator.com/ For those that are new to this concept, like me, there are three numbers (octals (?) of 3 bits each, i.e. 2^3, so from 0 - 7) XXX representing Owner permissions | Group permissions | Public permissions. Execute = 1, Write = 2, Read = 4, so Owner having all three (read-write-execute, i.e.: rwx) would = 7. If no one else has permissions, that's 700, as Anthon states above.